# How do I set a styleSheet for a custom titleBarWidget (for DockWidget) with global css

Tags: css, linux, qt, pyqt

I have a global file.css for ma Qt application

He works fine !

but I have a Custom widget for my titleBars of DockWidget

```
myDockWidget.setTitleBarWidget(myWidgetTitleBar(myDockWidget))
```

I don't find how to change styleSheet of this widget in my file.css

if I write in my class :

```
myWidgetTitleBar.setStyleSheet("Border:2px solid green; background-color:red;")
```

it doesn't works.

I tried :

file.css :

```
myWidgetTitleBar {  Border:2px solid green; background-color:red;  }
```

or, after have set in my class setObjectName("toto")

```
Widget#toto {  Border:2px solid green; background-color:red;  }
```

that's strange because all other widget with toto name works (green border and red bg), but this specific widget in my titlebar doesnt't.

(is the same when floating or not)

I tried this but same, doesn't work.

```
myDockWidget::title { Border:2px solid green; background-color:red; }
```

any Idea ? a Qt bug ?

I work with pyqt 4 on linux opensuse

Comment: Okay, I resolve this problem.

I created a widget inside wich take all the place, and with setObjectName and setstyleSheet classic, it works !